# rails - what is the best/most efficient way to associate these models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my application I have the following situation:

User belongs_to Group
Group has_many Users

Project belongs_to User
User has_many projects

The following is also true:
- Each Group will have one BaseCase
- Each Project will have multiple Scenarios and one BaseCase(depending on the Group the Project User belongs to)
- Scenario and BaseCase is the same type of object (let's call this Data)
- The default values for each Scenario are the BaseCase values for the Group, but the User can change these default values to create the specific Scenario

I am not sure how to capture all these relationships through associations efficiently, does anyone have any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then something like that

```
class User 
  belongs_to :group
  has_many   :projects
end 

class Group
  has_many :users
  has_many :projects, :through => :users
  has_one  :base_case
end

class Project
  has_many :scenarios
  has_one  :base_case
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :group, :through => user
  has_one :base_case, :through => :group
end  

class Scenario
  belongs_to :project
  has_one :base_case, :through => :project

  before_create do
    self.attributes = self.base_case.attributes.except(:group_id, ...)
  end
end

class BaseCase
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Comment: This is very useful thanks, does the self.attributes set the default values for the scenario? Also would this work without the lines containing ':through => :xxx'? thanks

Comment: 1. Yes, self.attributes = self.base_case.attributes.except(:group_id, ...) set the default values from base_case

2. No, :through => :xxx is required. It is generate SQL query like this: `select * from scenarios s inner join project p on p.id = s.project_id inner join groups ...  inner join base_cases b on b.group_id = g.id `

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer, unfortunately I don't have the rep to up vote you yet, but I've accepted the answer